# Regex for Phone Number validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am validate Phone Number. I would like to allow only `(123) 123-1234`. But my code is also allowing `123 123-1234`. My Regex is like below.

```
var format = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[ ]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: `\(?` and `\)?` mean the parentheses around the first 3 numbers are optional. You should remove these question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `?` quantifier for `(` and `)` in your regex, which matches your parentheses for **zero or one** times. Simply removing it will do the trick.

```
var format = /^\(([0-9]{3})\)[ ]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

Have a test for it [here](https://regex101.com/r/S1SUqm/1/)

Comment: @kol Thanks for pointing that out. Just had a bad coffee